# prime count using pthread but getting wrong result

Tags: c

I want to change this program so that if user inputs a number N it gives prime numbers upto N value. As I am new at this, I could not figure it. Please explain to me what am I missing. MAX_PRIME is my input arguement and candidate is the prime numbers i want to count.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>



int NUM_THREADS;
pthread_t *thread;
int MAX_PRIME;
int current = 1;
int candidate;

pthread_mutex_t thread_flag_mutex;

int get_next_candidate()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&thread_flag_mutex);
    int result=current++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&thread_flag_mutex);

    return result;
}


int compute_prime(int numPrime)
{
    int candidate = 2;
    while (1)
    {
        int factor;
        int is_prime = 1;

        /* Test primality by successive division.  */
        for (factor = 2; factor < MAX_PRIME; ++factor)
        {
            if (candidate % factor == 0)
            {
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (is_prime)
        {
            if (--numPrime == 0)
            {
                return candidate;
            }
        }    
        ++candidate;
    }

    return 0;
}


void* prime_job(void* t)
{

    long tid = (long ) t , total = 0 , result=0;


    printf("Thread %ld starting...\n", tid);

    while((candidate=get_next_candidate())<=MAX_PRIME){
        result=compute_prime(candidate);    
        printf("Thread %ld found prime: %ld\n",tid, result);

        ++total;
    }

    pthread_exit((void*) total);
}


//******************************* main 
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc<=1){
        printf("usag : prime MaxNumber [NUM_THREADS]");
        return 0;
    }

    else if (argc==2){
        //setting up the default thread value 
        MAX_PRIME=atoi(argv[1]);
        NUM_THREADS =2;
    }

    else{
        MAX_PRIME=atoi(argv[1]);
        NUM_THREADS=atoi(argv[2]);

    }


    //**************************** allocaion of memory

    candidate = malloc((candidate+1)*sizeof(int));
    thread = malloc(NUM_THREADS*sizeof(pthread_t));

    long t;

    // Start threads
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
        pthread_create(&thread[t], NULL, prime_job, (void *) t);

    // Join threads
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {
        void* numPrimesCalc;
        pthread_join(thread[t], &numPrimesCalc);
        printf("Thread %ld joined, calculated %ld prime numbers\n", t, (long) numPrimesCalc);
    }

    /* Print the largest prime it computed.  */

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly.

Comment: I am badly stuck, I am very new at this.

Comment: What's wrong with your program? Does it compile? Does it run? Do you understand what it's doing? Have you tried debugging it? You forgot to ask a question, which makes it very hard for us to answer.

Comment: What is your expected output, for example, when `MAX_PRIME = 10`?

Comment: What is `candidate = malloc((candidate+1)*sizeof(int));`?? You need a pointer to capture the return value, not an `int`!

Comment: if MAX_PRIME = 10 then output is supposed to be 2  3 5 7 . it compiles and runs. but it gives output 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 ( the 10 primes after the number 10 )

Comment: Can you explain what the `while (1)` is for? It's hard to debug code if we can only guess what it was intended to do, and your code has no comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
int compute_prime(int numPrime)
{
    int candidate = 2;
    while (1)
    {
        int factor;
        int is_prime = 1;

        /* Test primality by successive division.  */
        for (factor = 2; factor < MAX_PRIME; ++factor)
        {
            if (candidate % factor == 0)
```

If you're trying to test if `numPrime` is prime, `numPrime` needs to be on the left side of the `%`. Otherwise, you're testing the wrong number entirely.

Your `for` loops needs to stop before the number your testing. `x % x` will be zero for all `x` greater than zero. So you'll never find any primes if you test for factors that include the number you're testing for primality.

Also, what the heck is the `while (1)` for? This code looks like a result of cargo cult programming where things were placed in it because they helped solve completely different problems with no understanding.

Comment: Be careful not to consider `1` as prime number, if you don't want to consider as such.

Comment: the code was given like this, i had to edit and change to get prime numbers for an input of MAX_PRIME. i am very puzzled about the whole thing

Comment: Ahh, so you asked the wrong question! The question you should have asked is "explain this code", giving the *original* code. (To be more precise, you should ask specific questions about the parts of the code you don't understand.)

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. But any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: I suggest you don't try to modify code you don't understand and instead work on understanding it first. Add comments. Add logging. Run it under various conditions, maybe in a debugger. If necessary, confirm your understanding with others. The worst way to learn to code is to poke around in code you don't understand. It's frustrating and can even lead to unlearning. (Either code from scratch or analyze existing code.)